# C# Issue. Cannot get my labels to display the correct values according to my code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very new to C# development. I am currently trying to get my code to display 3 different messages depending on the button you click. So I have 3 buttons and 3 labels named 1,2,3 and A,B,C respectively. I have written the below code

```
namespace DemoChap2End
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Yes";
            label2.Text = "Yes";
            label3.Text = "Yes";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "No";
            label2.Text = "No";
            label3.Text = "No";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "A";
            label2.Text = "B";
            label3.Text = "C";
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the compiler, only button 1 seems to work and display the "Yes" for all 3 labels, button 2 and 3 do nothing. Am I missing something here in my code ? Or is it a button or text box property that needs to be adjusted. Please assist. New to C#
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are the events bound to the controls?

Comment: This is a job for debugging! You can select the first line of code in each method and hit <kbd>F9</kbd> - that'll put a breakpoint there. Now if you run your code (presumably it's already in debug mode) then your code will stop whenever it hits those lines. I suspect it won't stop for the second and third methods because they're not wired up properly.

Answer (score 1):

please check your buttons if they are bound to event you will find a picture to show you how to check an event click for a button .

[image: Button Properties]

Answer (score 0):

One click Button in Form and look properties>events>click event point to click method. If there is no click action for your button2 and button3, they don't give an action.

Or in Form design double clicked button which is not change the label value when you clicked code page appear and click method has already created for you.